# What would i type in GHCI to test this code

Tags: haskell

I'm new to haskell and came across some code on wikipedia

```
data Tree a = Tip | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a) deriving (Show,Eq)

height Tip = 0
height (Node _ xl xr) = 1 + max (height xl) (height xr)
```

source: http://www.csse.monash.edu.au/~lloyd/tildeFP/Haskell/1998/Tree/

I was wondering what would I have to type in GHCI to test this code, once i run the code from a file

Comment: `height Tip`, `height $ Node 1 (Node 2 Tip Tip) Tip` etc.

Comment: Thanks, what does the $ sign do?

Comment: It's the infix application operator, here it replaces parentheses, the second example could also be written `height (Node 1 (Node 2 Tip Tip) Tip)`. But the `$` is often considered more readable.

Comment: @dbaupp: since your comment was apparently the answer, you should post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following. If the code in your question is in a file "Main.hs" then do

```
$ ghci Main.hs
>> height Tip
0
>> height (Node "a" Tip Tip)
1
>> height (Node "a" Tip (Node "b" Tip Tip))
2
```

&c.